# Hexagon shaped image in React Native

Tags: react-native

I needed an `Image` or `Imagebackground` with the shape of a Hexagon. I have searched a lot but couldn't get any good answers.

In react I have seen something like `clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0 75%, 0 25%);` . Is there something similar in React native to achive hexagon shape for the image view.

Comment: Check this article:

https://medium.com/prototyped/react-native-svg-image-clippath-cf107ee9b812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with the library - [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-filter-kit)

This is mainly masking the image in the shape of another image.

Please follow the library linking for android and ios, please follow the tutorial in the above link for it.

code

```
import {DstATopComposition} from 'react-native-image-filter-kit';

<DstATopComposition 
  dstImage={
    <Image
      style={customStyle != null ? customStyle : style}
      resizeMode="contain"
      source={isBorder ? require("../../assets/images/whiteImage.png") : image }
    />
  }
  srcImage={
    <Image
      style={customStyle != null ? customStyle : style}
      resizeMode="contain"
      source={require('../../assets/images/hex-Image.png')}
    />
  }
/>
```

Comment: could you please share the code, it would be very helpful.